# 12.04 Command Line Failure to fetch

Tags: apt, updates

Basically I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a basic desktop that I had laying around.  And for the life on me I cannot get it to connect to the internet.  No matter what I do, It always gives me the "Failure to fetch" Then a url when I try to

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Also, I see a lot of people talking about opening certain windows, and going into certain settings, but I have none of that. Just a command line.

As you can tell I am extremely new to this.  I would really appreciate someone pointing me to somewhere I can learn about this.  I don't want someone to explain it to me, I would prefer if someone just walked me through where they go to solve their problems.  I apologize if this is an improper post, but I would want to learn it myself (teach a man to fish and all that).

Or if you know of any good walk through using command line, I would appreciate it.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: So your internet connection is not working? How do you connect to internet on windows?

Comment: It looks like there's more to this question than " I cannot get it to connect to the internet". There's also "I see a lot of people talking about opening certain windows, and going into certain settings, but I have none of that. Just a command line." which is quite a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the output. Which url can't be reached.
Have you checked this url also via web browser?

One reason may be an ppa repository that is not available any more.